# How to install wireless card on Kali Linux

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, virtualbox

I setup Kali Linux on VirtualBox. In terminal, airmon-ng command not showing up any wireless card. I've search for solving problem and here is the video that i follow: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rz46ISJYwLI

[image: (screenshot)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't *have* a wireless card. The guest OS only sees devices that are emulated by VirtualBox.

It can emulate regular Ethernet cards because those are easy to share between two computers; VirtualBox just needs to send packets over the same wire. However, wireless cards are much harder – the hardware must support running on multiple channels at the same time, one for host + one for every guest (although in practice they all might use the same channel), as well as support sending different MAC addresses for each VM (which is rather more complicated in WiFi than Ethernet).

That said, there *is* one way to move your real card into the VM – called ["PCI pass-through"](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#pcipassthrough) – but it means the *host* OS won't see the card anymore, it will temporarily become VM-only.